# AWS Load Balancer latency comparing between AZs (ap-south-1a / b / c)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I have an AWS classic load balancer with 3 instances in the Mumbai region with 3 instances in the ap-south-1a AZ. The website is serving the southern most of India (kerala) right now and only serving that very geography.

**I am wondering if there would be any latency differences if I choose the nearest availability zone?**

Ideally, I should choose the nearest availability zone for best lower latency, right ? Can anyone tell me if I choose the nearest AZ, it would be better? I checked the AWS documentation to understand their AZ location, could not find what would be nearest AZ for Kerala. If anyone knows can you guide me which one it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do that through the [Route53 "Latency" Route Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html#routing-policy-latency).

[image]

The ELBs still have to reside in one or more of the AZ's, doing it at the DNS level is a more effective way to route based on latency measures.

> Can anyone tell me if I choose the nearest AZ, it would be better?

AZ's are typically 100km or more apart and you should not notice the latency between AZ's in a single region.

> I checked the AWS documentation to understand their AZ location, could not find what would be nearest AZ for Kerala?

AWS do not reveal the exact location of data centres/AZ's due to security.

Also note, when you spin up a EC2 for example, when you choose the Subnet/AZ, those a, b, c are random - what you see is different to me (even using the same account) as that is how AWS internally load balance the resources among DC's/AZ's.So don't worry about it, I just leave the Subnet as the top choice or in scripts if I use less than 3 subnets (for DR not HA) then I'll randomly choose the subnet in my config. PS exmaple:

```
[string[]]$SubnetId = @(..,..)
if ($SubnetId.count -ge 2) {
  $stringSubnet = $SubnetId[(get-random -minimum 0 -maximum ($SubnetId.count - 1))]
} else {
  $stringSubnet = $SubnetId[0]
}
```